Using Google wallet api to generate transit passes getting error
I m trying to generate single url for google wallet transit passes , its working fine upto 3 passes , after adding more than 3 passes getting error and url https://pay.google.com/gp/v/save   not opening .
Is there any limit to add only 3 passes in google wallet or is there any size limit on google wallet url.
Tried adding usng multiple passes working with 3 passes after adding 4 passes getting error.
